# How to export packages to the presentation server?

Tags: abap

What i need to do is kind of a very restricted backup.

I've created a lot of small programs which i've put in my test package. In case the system goes down i'd like to keep my data. I also don't want to trouble the basis guys.

Firstly: is it a bad idea what i'm trying to achieve (cuz i really don't know much about SAP except for ABAP.
Secondly: (if it's a good idea) is it possible in a non "code copy-paste" way?

Comment: Try [SAPLink](http://code.google.com/p/saplink). Along with its plugins it allows you to "dump" the `ABAP` code into XML files.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's generally not necessary. SAP R/3 systems are usually mission-critical. If they go down, hit the basis administrators. If they take the system down without backing it up first and notifying everyone, hit them with a very large spiked club.

There are ways to download individual components ([SAPlink](http://www.saplink.org/) for example), but they are generally not (yet) complete - some object types are not supported. The best way to create such a backup is to add the objects to a transport, point it at a dummy destination (ask your basis admins to create one, they should know how to do this) and release it. Then grab the exported transport files (you could write a small report for this). It takes a little preparation, but this way you're sure you've got a backup that can be restored. Note that you'll need basis support for this. (For a developer, it's generally a good idea to keep good relations with the basis admins :-))

Comment: vielen dank! du bist der beste :D

Comment: @PasanIndeewara You didn't bother to follow the link, did you?

Answer (score 0):

Two approaches:

1. [SAPLink](https://wiki.scn.sap.com/wiki/display/ABAP/SAPlink)

More old-school way which uses files called **nuggets** for transferring objects between systems in a plain-text mode.

Supported on most systems [since version 4.6c](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E52090_13/otn/pdf/eip/E51847_01.pdf).

2. [abapGit](https://docs.abapgit.org/)

More modern way of moving ABAP developments using GIT concept. It allows [creating GIT repo from package](https://docs.abapgit.org/guide-moving-package.html) and pulling this repo onto any local machine.

Supported since BASIS v.702